# Select single row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

i have some trouble by retrieve only one row in case of duplicates or based on certain condition.

Let's say that i have a table like this:

**Datas:**

```
+-----+---------+------------+
| id: | caseId: |  userId:   |
+-----+---------+------------+
| a   |  3      |   sd87     |
| a   | <null>  |   sd87     |
| a   | <null>  |   sd87     |
| a   |  5      |   cz6      |
| b   | <null>  |    87      |
| b   | <null>  |    87      |
| b   | <null>  |    87      |
| d   |  22     |   ah54     |
| d   | <null>  |   ah54     |
| d   | <null>  |   fr45     |
| d   |  21     |   ah54     |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

What i need to extract is:

**Result:**

```
+-----+---------+------------+
| id: | caseId: |  userId:   |
+-----+---------+------------+
| a   |  3      |   sd87     |
| a   |  5      |    cz6     |
| b   | <null>  |    87      |
| d   |  22     |   ah54     |
| d   | <null>  |   fr45     |
| d   |  21     |   ah54     |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

I tried a query like this

```
select id,caseId,UserId
from datas
group by id,caseId,UserId
```

But it's not working on all scenario.

How should i change the query?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
explanation on which row i expected to keep.

with the same id, i consider at first userId with caseId associated. If caseId is null, then i keep the row with caseId NULL.

If a userId has one row with caseId and one or more row with caseId NULL, i'll keep the row with caseId NOT NULL.

IF a userId has two or more rows with caseId not null and different among them, i need to keep all of them. Of course, if i have also NULL rows, i'll not consider them.

Hope is more clear now.

EDIT2:

Thank's to @GordonLinoff to his solution that unfortunately it doesn't work woth my dataset

```
select distinct d.*
from datas d
where d.caseId is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from datas d2 
                  where d2.userid = d.userid and d2.caseid is not null
                 );
```

I added a codition in not exists subquery comparing also d2.id with d.id

```
select distinct d.*
from datas d
where d.caseId is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from datas d2 
                  where d2.id = d.id and d2.userid = d.userid and d2.caseid is not null
                 );
```

Now i obtain what i need.

Thank you all!

Comment: Why do you return 3 rows for d but only two rows for a? Why are two rows with NULL caseId values for a dropped entirely?

Comment: for the same Id, i consider first userId with caseId. For id 'a' i keep userId sd87 with caseId 3 and discard with caseId NULL associated at the same userId.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really aggregation.  It is more filtering:

```
select distinct d.*
from datas d
where d.caseId is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from datas d2 
                  where d2.userid = d.userid and d2.caseid is not null
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d68fcd0237e43e83f4b8f82bec4c193) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Tried both solution, but both exclude rows with null caseId

Comment: @Giacky Gordon's query works for me. Is it actually `NULL` or is it a string like `'<null>'` or `'null'`? Also why do you have two rows in your expected output for `id = d` and `userId = ah54`? Can you better explain what rules you are using when you eliminate rows from the output `in case of duplicates or based on certain condition`? What defines a duplicate? What other certain condition(s)?

Comment: Is it NULL. Let me edit the question answering your questions

Comment: @Giacky . . . The aggregation doesn't really work.  I added a db<>fiddle. that shows that the solution in the answer does work.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff. Don't know why it's not working with my dataset/db

Comment: @Giacky . . .  No idea.  I can only say that it works for the data in the question, which is shown in the db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i managed to obtain the result by adding d2.id= d.id in not exists sub query. I'll edit the main question adding both solutions

Answer (score 0):

I started from @GordonLinoff query and changed it to obtaind this result:

```
select distinct d.*
from datas d
where d.caseId is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from datas d2 
                  where d2.id = d.id and d2.userid = d.userid and d2.caseid is not null
                 );
```

I added the condition on `d2.id = d.id`